# How to insert to existing Firebase DB array using Firebase Functions in javascript

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to build an app that stores and shows book quotes by it's title and by it's author. I am using Firebase for the backend. My Firebase data structure looks like this.

[image]

When a book quote is added, I know the author. So to store the quote in author automatically, I am trying to use Firebase Functions.

I have tried two approaches,

**Merge quotes from author with quotes from the book when book is updated.**

```
exports.newQuotesTrigger = functions.database.ref('library/{bookAndAuthor}').onWrite((snap, context) => {
    const message = snap;
    console.log('Retrieved message content: ', message);

    const newValue = message.after.val();
    const oldValue = message.before.val();

    const author = snakeCase(newValue.author);
    admin.database().ref('authors/' + author).child('quotes').set(newValue.quotes);
    console.log('Updated author quotes');

    return message;
});
```

**Just push the difference of new quotes and old quotes from the book**

```
exports.newQuotesTrigger = functions.database.ref('library/{bookAndAuthor}').onWrite((snap, context) => {
    const message = snap;
    console.log('Retrieved message content: ', message);

    const newValue = message.after.val();
    const oldValue = message.before.val();

    const newQuotes = newValue.quotes || [];
    const oldQuotes = oldValue.quotes || [];
    const diff = arrayDiff(newQuotes, oldQuotes);

    if (diff) {
        console.log('Quotes were updated for ', {title: newValue.title, author: newValue.author});
        const author = snakeCase(newValue.author);
        admin.database().ref('authors/' + author).child('quotes').push(diff);
        console.log('Updated author quotes');
    }

    return message;
});
```

Both don't append/insert update quotes properly. I haven't found a way to append/insert to a Firebase db array.

Comment: you can try to insert all the array and not a single row

Comment: You mean fetch author quotes, update then set? Why is it not clear in documentation?

Comment: yes i do in this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use update in order to "update specific children of a node without overwriting other child nodes", see:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Your first piece of code should work with update if you slightly change your structure as follow with autogenerated Ids for the quotes

**Database**

```
author
    - nassim
      - quoteID1: "...."  <- ID auto generated
      - quoteID2: "...."  <- ID auto generated
      - quoteID3: "...."  <- ID auto generated
```

**Cloud Function**

Replace, in your first version of the code, these lines

```
    admin.database().ref('authors/' + author).child('quotes').set(newValue.quotes);
    console.log('Updated author quotes');
    return message;
```

by those ones

```
  const quotesObject = newValue.quotes;
  var updates = {};      

  Object.keys(quotesObject).forEach(function (key) {
    let quote = quotesObject[key];
    const newQuoteKey = firebase.database().ref('authors/' + author).child('quotes').push().key;
    updates[newQuoteKey] = quote ;
  });

  return admin.database().ref('authors/' + author).child('quotes').update(updates);
```

Another important point is that you are not returning a promise in your Cloud Functions. You should return the promise from the update (or set) and not the message. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&t=26s

---

In case you really have to keep the quotes id generated by yourself (i.e. 0, 1, 2, etc) in a sequence you will have to manipulate arrays by getting the previous array of values, adding the new quote and overwriting the existing set of quotes with the new array.. a lot of efforts! especially that with auto-generated ids you will not loose the quotes order: they will still be saved in the order they were written.

Comment: But I have multiple books by same author. update will override and put quotes from updated book I think. I'll check on promises.

Comment: No Update will not overwritre.The problem you may have is that you store the quotes with an index you build yourself, i.e. 0, 1, 2 etc. Do you really need that? Using an auto generated index would make your Cloud Function much easier

Comment: I have updated my answer for the case you auto generate the keys

Comment: The `.update(updates)` will push all new quotes as a separate object instead of merging even if I change data structure

Comment: No, it will add an extra child node under the `nodes` quote (unless I have made a mistake in the code of my answer). This is how `update()` works.

Comment: It adds a new quotes node with all new quotes. So I if I go on adding book quotes, author quotes will go on having new nodes with all new corresponding quotes. I don't how can I make use of that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169931/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-hussain).

Comment: Sure. You can also refer https://github.com/hussaintamboli/firebase-functions-organise-book-quotes